# Regex lookahead in powershell

Tags: regex, powershell

I am trying to pull information from a route print file dump of a legacy server and parse it using regex.  As part of that, I'm trying to pull out just the IPv4 route information.  The file looks like this...

```
IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1     192.168.0.24     20
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
  1    306 ::1/128                  On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

And I'm trying a lookbehind/lookahead method `(?<=ce  Metric)(?s)(.*)(?=={75})`to get the IPv4 route out like so.

```
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1     192.168.0.24     20
```

The problem I'm experiencing with what I have is that the lookahead, `(?=={75})`, is capturing the last instance of the 75 equal signs instead of the next one after the lookbehind is found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your capture group lazy (`?`) so it will match as few characters as possible (stop at the first match of `={75}`)

```
(?<=ce  Metric)(?s)(.*?)(?=={75})
```

[Sample Regex101](https://www.regex101.com/r/lQ7yZ7/1)

Comment: Dang, one character off.  That works perfectly.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, this would be a lot easier with a multi-line single-line regex:

```
$regex = 
@'
(?ms)IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
(.+?)
===========================================================================
'@

(Get-Content route_print.txt -Raw) -match $regex > $null
$Matches[1]
```

Comment: It's"cleaner, but the solution in your answer is also the lazy operator. :)

Comment: Agreed.  It's just a different approach to the problem, but it's easy to code (most of the work is done with copy/paste from the match data), and it's a lot more intuitive to read later.